# Remove Vertical Line in the center of the VS Code Editor view

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I remove this vertical line from the VS Code Editor view? I have looked at the various settings and can find no way to remove it.

> Version: 1.36.1 (user setup)
>   Commit: 2213894ea0415ee8c85c5eea0d0ff81ecc191529
>   Date: 2019-07-08T22:59:35.033Z
>   Electron: 4.2.5
>   Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
>   Node.js: 10.11.0
>   V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
>   OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.16299

[image]

Answer (score 18):

Go Settings - Rules - Edit in settings.json - Quit a number

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the image - didn't realise Dart was overriding this until your image showed it.

Comment: I have no entries for rulers but I still have the vertical line.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\useraccount\AppData\Roaming\Code\User

Navigate here and remove the number from Settings.json as mentioned above by @David.